# Why IR remote waveform is a saw-tooth or am I measuring it wrong

Tags: measurement, infrared, remote-control, waveform

The measurement circuit is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbOpNS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The waveform looks like this in my measurement:

[image: Samsung remote waveform]

Is this because I'm measuring it wrong and the diode current source with a capacitance somewhere forms an integrator hence the triangle wave, or is it really a triangle wave?

If really a triangle wave what is the reason for using it instead of a simple on-off modulation?

**Edit:** trying with different remotes now and get triangle waves everywhere so I suppose it's a parasitic capacitance from the cathode of the diode to ground, probably because I'm using a breadboard.

Comment: as a side note, you could get clean waveforms by skipping the opamp and placing your probe at the photodiode's terminals. If you are very close with your remote you can also use normal LEDs.

Comment: I tried something similar, but with a resistor to ground. The problem I had was the mains coupled noise overwhelming the weak signal from the diode (I tried a LED, not a photodiode)

Comment: Try the diode directly connected to the probe. Also your 37.59 kHz frequency is suspiciously close to the 38-39 kHz modulation frequency of most remote controls. What I see with my remote are 800mV pulses with 200mV superimposed modulation at 38 kHz.

Comment: @SredniVashtar This IS a remote control, for a Samsung TV. Will try with the photodiode directly connected. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, what I meant is that what you are seeing is the modulation on top of the pulses (straighten out by the slew-rate limit of the op amp), while you might be looking for the pulses themselves, which happen at a much lower frequency. I had no problems with mains noise, despite the timebase being set to 10ms/div. Yes, I could see a slight sinusoidal bump at the base of the signal, but it was maybe 10-20 mV, at most a tenth of division at 200mV/div. (Also, the modulation was triangular like - with exponential rise and fall, probably due to the diode capacitance, or maybe that's the way it is).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the TI LM358 datasheet, the maximum output slew rate of your op-amp is about 0.3 V/us:

[image]

Your scope trace shows the signal has a slope of about 3 V per 10 us, pretty well matching the datasheet limit.

This is simply the fastest edge an LM358 is able to produce at its output.

To achieve a faster edge, you'll need to choose a different op-amp.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this, and it's a straight line, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your TIA to work properly change 1M to 10k and then followed by an AC coupled self biased buffered logic inverter with a gain of 100. You can offset the input lightly to squelch for idle noise, or use a precision comparator.

Comment: Who was the inexperienced -1?  Reducing R precludes the Slew Rate issue and extends the BW 100x